# neo4j Atlas - country region codes in Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher, country-codes

I need to point entities to countries, and countries to regions. There are plenty of lists of countries and their codes online, and I am wondering if anyone has built a "country tree", or a neo4j "atlas" and made the Cypher commands available?

Something like:

```
MERGE (:Country{name: "Afghanistan", alpha2:"AF", alpha3: "AFG"}) -[:IS_IN]->(sr:SUB_REGION{name: "Southern Asia"})
MERGE (sr)-[:IS_IN]->(r:REGION{name: "Asia"})
MERGE (r)-[:IS_IN]->(p:Planet{name: "World"})
```

... for the entire world?

If not, I will do it myself and share!

Comment: Not exactly what you are looking for, but can help. From Graph Gist: [Frontières Terrestres / World Borders](https://neo4j.com/graphgist/b61499a8-a733-4b69-8b1e-20866734d597) by Matthieu Totet. Can be a good start point to achieve your goal.

Comment: I remember doing that by going to wikipedia for the country code -> country name list, copy and paste into vim, and then using a search and replace. Since it was from an old job, I don't have the exact cypher any more.

Comment: Thanks. I did that to grab a list of countries and codes, then wrote a python script to create the tree. It is here https://github.com/Mwanafunzi/Neo4j-Python if anyone is interested.